# Changing a label text at the start and the end of an ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

I have a process to be performed in an ActionListener call. This process can take some time. So I have to inform that is processing during the time of the execution in a label.

My problem is that Swing doesn't repaint the label during the thread of ActionListener, so I can't show the "Processing" message.

What is the best way to solve that?

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyTestPane extends JPanel{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 340444475514103360L;
    private JLabel myLabel;
    private JButton myButton;
    
    public MyTestPane() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
    private void initComponents() {
        myLabel = new JLabel("Ready");
        myButton = new JButton("Start");
        myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                myActionListenter();
            }
        });
        add(myLabel);
        add(myButton);
    }

    private void myActionListenter(){
        myLabel.setText("Starting count ...");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        myLabel.setText("Finishing count ...");
    }
    
    public static final void main(String argv[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new MyTestPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply said, in another thread. There are several possibilities, like an old-fashioned `Thread`, an `Executor` or maybe `SwingWorker`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to do something heavy (in terms of time required to be finished), like `Thread.sleep`, you can't simply do it in the same thread the GUI runs. When your heavy task starts on the same thread as the GUI, the GUI thread is busy calculating your heavy task and therefore it cannot receive any events. That's why the whole GUI freezes. Because it is busy.

Now in order to solve that read [concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

To sum it up for you, all Swing applications must run on their single-per-application thread. This thread is called the Event Dispatch Thread. Because all GUI events (mouse pointers moving, buttons clicked, windows resizing, etc) happen there.

So, when you want to do something heavy, you do it in another thread and since they are invisible to the user(GUI) they are called background threads. Swing has its own API to create background threads. They are called SwingWorkers. You can find how to use one in the doc.

Here is an example of doing something heavy (`Thread.sleep`) and at the same time publishing the progress (I don't know if you are interested in that). Also, I try to keep things some sort of abstract, in order to keep the concerns separated.

I suggest you to run it and have some experiments with it.

```
public class WorkerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
            myPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(myPanel);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private static class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ProgressableView {
        private JLabel countLabel;
        private JProgressBar progressBar;

        public MyPanel() {
            super(new FlowLayout());

            countLabel = new JLabel("Progress: 0");
            add(countLabel);

            progressBar = new JProgressBar();
            progressBar.setVisible(false);
            add(progressBar);

            JButton startHeavyTaskButton = new JButton("Start Heavy Task");
            startHeavyTaskButton.addActionListener(e -> {
                startHeavyTaskButton.setEnabled(false);
                startHeavyTaskButton.setText("Please wait..");
                progressBar.setValue(0);
                progressBar.setVisible(true);

                Runnable restoreButtonAvailability = () -> {
                    startHeavyTaskButton.setEnabled(true);
                    startHeavyTaskButton.setText("Start Heavy Task");

                };
                new DoSomethingHeavyAndShowProgressWorker(this, restoreButtonAvailability).execute();
            });

            add(startHeavyTaskButton);
        }

        @Override
        public void setProgress(int progress) {
            if (progress >= 99) {
                countLabel.setText("Finished!!");
                progressBar.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                progressBar.setValue(progress);
                countLabel.setText("Progress: " + progress);
            }

        }

    }

    private static interface ProgressableView {
        void setProgress(int progress);
    }

    private static class DoSomethingHeavyAndShowProgressWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

        private ProgressableView view;
        private Runnable onDone;

        public DoSomethingHeavyAndShowProgressWorker(ProgressableView view, Runnable onDone) {
            this.view = view;
            this.onDone = onDone;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                publish((i + 1)); // Publish will call process() method in the GUI thread
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
            if (chunks.isEmpty())
                return;

            int progress = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
            view.setProgress(progress);
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                get(); // To catch exceptions happend in background
                if (onDone != null)
                    onDone.run();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a preview:

[image: preview]

Answer (score 1):

I put the counter code in a separate thread so it would run separately from the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) that all Swing components must be created and executed.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TimerTestPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 340444475514103360L;
    private JLabel myLabel;
    private JButton myButton;

    public TimerTestPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        myLabel = new JLabel("Ready");
        myButton = new JButton("Start");
        myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                myActionListenter();
            }
        });
        add(myLabel);
        add(myButton);
    }

    private void myActionListenter() {
        myLabel.setText("Starting count ...");
        new Thread(new Counter()).start();
    }

    public static final void main(String argv[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TimerTestPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
    public class Counter implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myLabel.setText("Finishing count ...");
                }
            });
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can use an invokeLater to perform the process, so the ActionListener can change the label without waiting de long process to be finished, but I don't if it is the best solution.

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyTestPane extends JPanel{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 340444475514103360L;
    private JLabel myLabel;
    private JButton myButton;
    
    public MyTestPane() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
    private void initComponents() {
        myLabel = new JLabel("Ready");
        myButton = new JButton("Start");
        myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                myActionListenter();
            }
        });
        add(myLabel);
        add(myButton);
    }

    private void myActionListenter(){
        myLabel.setText("Starting count ...");
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                myLabel.setText("Finishing count ...");
                
            }
        });
    }
    
    public static final void main(String argv[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new MyTestPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```